# Error add library TomShane.Neoforce.Controls.dll

Tags: silverlight, dll, xna

My project uses library `TomShane.Neoforce.Controls.dll`. It gives me the following error message:

> Error 6 The type or namespace name 'TomShane' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the namespace called inside the DLL?

Comment: it is GameComponent.cs XNA Game Studito 4.0

Comment: That's not what I asked. You're making an assumption that the namespace is TomShane.NeoForce.Controls; I just want to know where you're getting that. In that DLL, what are the namespace(s) used? You should browse its metadata to find that out.

Comment: in metadata namespace it used: "TomShane.Neoforce.Controls"

Comment: Check the path of the reference and ensure the DLL file resides at that path. Try a Rebuild.